# Get Wall Owner when linked to Canvas app

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-wall

I am creating a canvas app that, in order to proceed, the owner of the wall must match the user who clicked on the link.

I can get the userID, but now I'm wondering how to get the wall's owner's UserID within the canvas app.

How would I go about getting the Wall's owner's ID?

I'd prefer an answer entirely in C#.

Comment: Are you using the graph API or FBML

Comment: Actually, using the JavaScript SDK

Comment: The owner of 'the' wall? What do you mean by this? 
Is this a page tab app and you want to know if the user viewing the tab is an admin of the page?